# How to pass a data like a database data or php constant data to display in a form in main.js

Tags: sulu, aura.js

We build  a custom bundle  follow with this instructor https://blog.sulu.io/how-to-develop-a-bundle-in-the-sulu-admin-1
We need to know how to pass data from a database to render radio input choices or dropdown select.

We try to create an add/edit form and in the form, we have a radio and dropdown we made with hardcore in HTML file in Vendor/TransportationBundle/Resources/public/js/components/transportation/form/form.html

The code is

```
<div class="grid-row">
    <label for="transportation-transportationType"><%= translations.transportationType %></label>
    <div class="custom-radio">
        <input name="transportationType" id="transportation-transportationType-1" type="radio"
               class="form-element content-type" value="1" data-mapper-property="transportationType">
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="clickable"><%= translations.private_shuttle %></span>
    <div class="custom-radio">
        <input name="transportationType" id="transportation-transportationType-2" type="radio"
               class="form-element content-type" value="2" data-mapper-property="transportationType">
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="clickable"><%= translations.shared_shuttle %></span>
    <div class="custom-radio">
        <input name="transportationType" id="transportation-transportationType-3" type="radio"
               class="form-element content-type" value="3" data-mapper-property="transportationType">
        <span class="icon"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="clickable"><%= translations.airplane %></span>
</div>
```

Is this have a way to change those radio to fetch the data from an array or a way to fetch the data from some controller action? or Have another way to use twig file with twig feature instead of html file?

Please provide a solution for us? Thank you

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can e.g. check [this Controller from the core](https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/master/src/Sulu/Bundle/AudienceTargetingBundle/Controller/TemplateController.php#L90). You can get data from wherever you want in the controller and pass it to the template:

```php
<?php
class AcmeController {
    public function testAction() {
        $data = /* Get data somehow */;

        return $this->render('template', ['data' => $data]);
    }
}
```

Then you can access the data using the `data` twig variable in the rendered template.